# Randint isnt being recognised as a function? I Cant figure this out

Tags: python

```
import random
min = 1
max = 6

roll_again = "yes"

while roll_again == "yes" or roll_again == "y":
    print ("Rolling the dices...")
    print ("The values are....")
    print random.randint(min, max)
    print random.randint(min, max)

    roll_again = raw_input("Roll the dices again?")
```

and this is the error

```
  File "main.py", line 10
    print random.randint(min, max)
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Where am I going wrong and how do I fix ?

Comment: If this is Python 3 then `print` needs parentheses. `print(random.randint(min, max))`

Comment: `raw_input` would suggest python2, no?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I added Parentheses but that is not the problem, it is still giving me syntax's

Comment: +Harry are you using python 2 or 3?

Comment: Also, `min` and `max` are built in functions and you should probably not use them as variable names.

Comment: I don't get errors with this on Python2.7

Comment: Im using python 3 @QWERTYL

Comment: Should I be using python 2.7 @Mark

Comment: raw_input has been renamed to input in python 3

Comment: No, you should use 3. But then you need `input()` instead of `raw_input()` and `()` in your print.

Comment: No, you should NOT be using Python 2.7.  You should update the syntax so it's correct for Python 3.

Comment: @QWERTYL  Now the program runs, but gives me a runtime error, responding this 
Rolling the dices...
The values are....
6 
2 
Roll the dices again?
Traceback (most recent call last): File "main.py", line 13, in <module> roll_again = input("Roll the dices again?") EOFError: EOF when reading a line Now the program runs,

Comment: The program runs fine for me. An EOF error means you didn't pass any input to the program, and just clicked enter.

Comment: @QWERTYL Enter is not the same as EOF, I truly don't understand that error.  But it's all irrelevant, the question as asked is answered.

Answer (score 2):

You need parentheses for your `print()` calls. Try this:

```
print(random.randint(min, max))
```

Also, since you're using Python 3 you should use `input()` instead of `raw_input()`.

Comment: You should add an explanation of why the error was pointing to the wrong part of the line.

Answer (score 1):

Between Python 2.7 and Python 3.0, `print` changed from a statement to a function.  The line producing your error was perfectly valid in Python 2.7, but functions require their arguments to be enclosed in parentheses.  In this case, Python encountered a function name that wasn't followed by an opening parenthesis so it didn't know how to interpret what followed.  Even though the error pointed to `random` as the problem, the error actually occurred prior to that.  As [@QWERTYL pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67629586/5987) the solution is very simple, turn the `print` into a proper function call by putting the arguments inside parentheses.

```
print(random.randint(min, max))
```

P.S. don't use variable names like `min` and `max`, those are already used by Python itself and can lead to some hard to find bugs.  Maybe `smallest` and `largest` would be better.